# Vegan Cheese - Almond Milk Curdle

Tags: cheese, vegan, dairy-free

Does almond milk curdle?

I tried to make it curdle to make vegan cheese. I added vinegar and cooked it and nothing happened. I continued to cook off all the water and was left with essentially an almond paste. How do you make a colloid like this curdle more to make it like cheese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vegan cheeses are typically mot made by curdling a vegan milk. As you have noticed, vegan milks don't curdle when you introduce an acid. Vegan cheeses tend to be made by either making a nut paste with some add-ins to give it a nice flavour and texture, or by thickening a vegan milk mixture with some starch or agar agar.

Comment: This is not actually true - it is entirely possible to curdle nut based milks (and I have done so many times). Some store bought brands do contain certain stabilising agents that stop curdling though, so it is best to make your own plant milk to achieve this.